# Using 3 Pipes(FIFO) to communicate in c , blocking when I tried to communicate with third

Tags: c, linux, fifo

I have the following issue. I have two clients each one has one pipe for reading called .name_of_client and I have a pipe for writing to the server with constant name.
When client 1 sends a message to the server then sends a message to same client (possible success message) but when I tried to send to client 2 the server gets trapped , it can't receive another message  , and client2 must only read a pipe if have something on them I tried `while(!feof(fd))` but it doesn't appear to work. Am I using the wrong function for the job?

My code only necessary to get more information of what I'm doing:
It's only a essential part of my code
server:

```
void  process_msg(char* s){
 char* from;
 char* to;
 char* msg;

 strtok(s,":");
 from = strtok(NULL,",");
 strtok(NULL,":");
 to = strtok(NULL,",");
 strtok(NULL,":");
 msg = strtok(NULL,";");


 char path[50];
 char path2[50];

 sprintf(path,".%s",from);
 sprintf(path2,".%s",to);

 char buffer[250];

 if((fp = fopen(path, "w")) == NULL) {
    perror("fopen");
    exit(1);
 }

 if(strcmp(from,to)==0){
  sprintf(buffer,"não podes enviar uma mensagem a ti proprio");
  fputs(buffer,fp);
  fclose(fp);
  return;
 }
 int is_online =0;
 int i=0;
 for(i=0;i<tamanho;i++)
 if(strcmp(list[i].user,to)==0)
  is_online =1;

 if(!is_online){
  sprintf(buffer,"%s nao esta online!\n",to);
  fputs(buffer,fp);
  fclose(fp);
  return;
 }
 else
  printf("-> %s mandou uma mensagem a %s\n",from,to);
  fputs("ENVIADO",fp);
  fclose(fp);
  printf("%s",path2);

  if((fp = fopen(path2, "w")) == NULL) {
    perror("fopen");
    exit(1);
  }
  sprintf(buffer,"%s > %s\n",from,msg);
  fputs(buffer,fp);
  fclose(fp);

 }
```

client:

```
 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
  FILE *fp;

  if(argc==1){
   printf("Não escolheu utilizador\n");
   exit(0);
  }
  char* password;
  sprintf(user,"%s",argv[1]);
  printf("Password:\n");
  password = get_password();

  char mensagem[250];

  if((fp = fopen(FIFO_FILE, "w")) == NULL) {
    perror("fopen");
    exit(1);
  }

  strcpy(path,".");
  strcat(path,user);
  umask(0);
  mknod(path, S_IFIFO|0666, 0);

  sprintf(mensagem,"U:%s,%s;",user,password);
  fputs(mensagem, fp);
  fclose(fp);
  if((fp = fopen(path, "r")) == NULL) {
      perror("fopen");
      exit(1);
  }
  fgets(mensagem,250,fp);
  fclose(fp);

  if(strcmp(mensagem,"SUCCESS")==0){
   printf("\n\nUtilizador %s autenticado. Pode começar a usar o sistema!\n\n",user);
  }
  else if(strcmp(mensagem,"FAIL!")==0){
   printf("Password incorrecta!\n");
   exit(1);
  }


  while(1){
      printf("name\n"); //DEBUG
      if((fp = fopen(path, "r")) == NULL) {
          perror("fopen");

          exit(1);
        }

        printf("name2");//DEBUG
      while(fgets(mensagem,250,fp)!=NULL){
        printf("%s",mensagem);
      }

      fclose(fp);

   printf("**Menu**\n1) Listar utilizadores online\n2) Mandar SMS a um utilizador\n3) Logout\n\n");

   char opcao;
   op:deactivate_input();
   scanf("%c",&opcao);
   activate_input();


   if(opcao!='1' && opcao!='2' && opcao!='3')
     goto op;
   if(opcao=='1'){
    if((fp = fopen(FIFO_FILE, "w")) == NULL) {
     perror("fopen");
     exit(1);
    }
    sprintf(mensagem,"W:%s;",user);
    fputs(mensagem, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    if((fp = fopen(path, "r")) == NULL) {
     perror("fopen");
     exit(1);
    }
    printf("////ONLINE LIST\\\\\\\\");
    while(!feof(fp)){
     fgets(mensagem, 250, fp);
     printf("%s\n",mensagem);
    }
    printf("////  END\\\\\\\\\n");
    fflush(fp);
    fclose(fp);

    }
    else if(opcao=='2'){

    if((fp = fopen(FIFO_FILE, "w")) == NULL) {
        perror("fopen");
        exit(1);
    }
    char tmp[50];
    printf("Para quem vais mandar a mensagem?\n");
    scanf("%s",tmp);
    getchar();
    printf("Escreve a mensagem?\n");
    //scanf("%s",mensagem);
    strcpy(mensagem,"");
    char s[50];
    fgets(mensagem,250,stdin);

    char buffer[500];
    sprintf(buffer,"F:%s,T:%s,M:%s;",user,tmp,mensagem);
    fputs(buffer, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    if((fp = fopen(path, "r")) == NULL){
     perror("fopen");
     exit(1);
    }
    fgets(mensagem, 250, fp);
    fclose(fp);
    if(strcmp(mensagem,"ENVIADO")==0){

    }else{
     printf("%s\n",mensagem);
    }

}
else if(opcao=='3'){
 if((fp = fopen(FIFO_FILE, "w")) == NULL) {
    perror("fopen");
    exit(1);
}
sprintf(mensagem,"R:%s;",user);
fputs(mensagem, fp);
fclose(fp);
break;
}

}

return(0);
}
```

UPDATE: I used two strings to debug but name2 is never printed. I am sure the fp is not busy but it never enters on f((fp = fopen(path, "r")) == NULL) 
Does someone know why it stops before it enters on while cause prints name1 but I have nothing in between.

Comment: Fyi, `while(!feof(fp))` = bad idea. [Read here for why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong).

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but why use a temporary buffer for the strings? Why not use `fprintf` to print directly to the file?

Comment: so I must use fgets(...)!=NULL them?